# Examples of technical interview questions for junior Ruby / Ruby on Rails developer position?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are resources on stack for what a junior developer *should know* but notsomuch on *specific interview questions* that employers are likely to ask.

Particularly interested in junior level questions both because it's relevant to me and juniors inherently have less experience so could use the advice.

I've solicited and found advice that a jr rails dev should know the following areas but would love to know any *interview questions* people have encountered.

- How MVC works
- Data structures
- Define Yield, Blocks, Enumerables, Class vs Instance variables
- How the internet works (high level), how does data flow between your application and the end user
- *Any other questions you've seen?*

Note, I've seen a lot of similar questions [closed] on stack, but I looked at the question guidelines and imho asking for specific examples of technical interview questions is well within the guidelines, so I hope people will let this question live :)

Comment: am just nitpicking but #4 is better written as how a web application works.. the internet technically is 1 lvl below

Comment: The main point is to get if applicant is able to think. Not really if he already knows.

Comment: Could be interesting to see if applicant knows his tools and limitations. Example: if he knows SO is not the appropriate place for this kind of debates.

Comment: To those who put this question on hold as "primarily opinion-based" I did not ask for opinions so much as *specific examples of questions*. If SO is not the place for this type of question, I suggest revising the question guidelines as I double-checked them before posting (i.e. under the 4th bullet I believe this question is "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession").